# Django settings and view mapping error

Tags: python, django, node.js, sqlite

I have build a realtime notification app using Django(1.8.5). I am using django server, Nodejs as push server, ishout.js[nodejs+redis +express.js API]. So I installed them by following the instructions.

Kindly suggest how this error can be fixed :

settings.py file

```
"""
#Django settings for realtimenotif project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'gvvs-0*-cohfbm@()*nyt&0u!77sc_8vnw%1afpkmhi&y-6&ds'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True


ADMINS = (
             #'arunsingh','arunsingh.in@gmail.com'
    )

MANAGERS = ADMINS

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'drealtime',
    'sendnotif',

)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (

    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'drealtime.middleware.iShoutCookieMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'realtimenotif.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug':DEBUG,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

            ],
        },
    },
]



WSGI_APPLICATION = 'realtimenotif.wsgi.application'





# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),

        #The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER':'',
        'PASSWORD':'',
        'HOST':'',                  # Empty for localhost through domain sockets,127.0.0.1
        'PORT':'',                  # Set to empty string for default
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

urls.py file

```
"""realtimenotif URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Add an import:  from blog import urls as blog_urls
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include(blog_urls))
"""
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
#from sendnotif.views import home, alert

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns(['',

    url(r'^$', 'sendnotif.views.home', name='home'),
    #url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^alert/$', 'sendnotif.views.alert', name='alert'),
    #url(r'^alert/$', alert, name='alert'),

    url(r'^accounts/login/$','django.contrib.auth.views.login',name='login'),

    #uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/$', include(admin.site.urls)), 
]   )
```

Django server is starting, it says works and gives this message

> "You're seeing this message because you have DEBUG = True in your
>   Django settings file and you haven't configured any URLs. Get to
>   work!"

What changes I have to make in my settings.py and views.py file, Kindly suggest pointers to workaround. I have gone through [official django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#django-conf-urls-patterns) and beginner tutorials, but to no rescue.

You can see the project source code at [githubRepo](https://github.com/arunsingh/real_time_notification)

Comment: Instead of [deleting your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32963521/1324033) and making a new one, you should address (and read) the comments in that question and update/edit your question accordingly

Comment: Please don't post a link to your repository and ask us to fix your code. Post the relevant code here on Stack Overflow. You might find it easier to work through the tutorial and get the simple polls app working, rather than jumping in and installing Django, node, ishout, and so on all at once.

Comment: @Alasdair I am not at all asking to fix the code, That repo is just for look out, Next time Onwards, I will tryi best to post relevant code, Moderators in previous question suggested that It was not focusing on one problem, Instead problem is broad, Hence I tried to fix that by narrowing the problem.

Comment: You have focussed on one error, but you are not showing us the code that is causing the problem. At the moment you are asking us to go and look at your repository to find out what is wrong. You can [edit] your question and add the relevant code. In particular, you need to show what `ROOT_URLCONF` is in your settings, and show the contents of the urls.py that it points to.

Comment: I just tried to add code, but edit is not being done, Kindly point out the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django fails to find your urls.py file.

You need to point the root URLconf at the `realtimenotif.urls` module. Create a top level `urls.py` and use an include(), eg:

yoursite/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^/', include('realtimenotif.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

or alternatively move your urls.py from realtimenotif to the top level folder.